# How do I get Openshift to let Tomcat retain it's hosted site's changes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have a pod in Redhat Openshift running Tomcat and inside Tomcat I have Ozone Widget Framework, my site hosted in Tomcat. I have executed the `oc` command to use my existing configuration so that my pod won't disappear and lose my session and data. I ran

`oc cluster up --host-data-dir=/path_to_data/openshiftdata --use-existing-config`

But after making changes within OWF, when I take down the cluster and bring it back up my pod lives on, but my OWF instance is reverted back to it's default state.

How do I get Openshift to let Tomcat retain OWF's state?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Persitent Volume](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html).

Your `/path_to_data/openshiftdata` is probably on a disk that belongs to the pod and is being destroyed each time.

Comment: My path_to_data is set to a folder in my home directory, I don't think it can be owned by the pod. My Openshift project and it's pod were being destroyed when I shut down Openshift until I started using the switches above.

Comment: I undeleted this post as it looks like a valuable answer to me. Please let me know if you disagree.